# does tdengine support recursive query？

Tags: tdengine

I transfer business logic from mysql to tdengine. Since our sql logic is is very
Complex,we used lots of nested join and recursive query. I want to ask that is any way know does tdengine support recursive query? And nested sql?

Answer (score 0):

TDengine supports nested query as far as I know. The depth of the nested query  is limited to 2 through my own test. Not sure if they support more layers as of now and you can give it a try.